# Determine point of intersection between two geographic rays

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

We are currently looking for an equation to calculate the geographic point of intersection when given two geographic rays, where both thetas are angles based off true north (the bearing). Both points have different latitudes and longitudes. We are not very familiar with the intricacies of calculating points for geographic locations, so any help or information is greatly appreciated!

Furthermore, I apologize for the quality of the image, I drew it quickly. Each theta should be numbered 1 & 2 respectfully.

[image: Picture of problem]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is a *geographic vector*? How is the *geographic point of intersection* defined?

Comment: You have given two points not lines or vectors.

Comment: Are the points (and the "geographic" vectors, whatever that is) supposed to lie on the surface of a sphere? Or you are talking about points and vectors on the plane (true north is a point at infinity)?

Comment: Are you pretending the earth is a sphere?

Comment: Each geographic vector determines a great circle on the Earth's "sphere" although Earth is not precisely a sphere. The great circles have two points of intersection. Here is one possible resource: http://www.dirkbertels.net/computing/greatCircles_files/great_circles_070206.pdf

Comment: Here is another resource, perhaps more accessible: http://enrico.spinielli.net/understanding-great-circle-arcs_57/

Comment: Hi, it is not a vector, it is a ray. We have a geographic point with a line of bearing (the theta) and we need to find an intersection between these rays. We can assume the earth is a sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrating the comments by @JohnWaylandBales:

---

[image: Arcs]

          

<sup>Great-circle arcs lie on planes through the sphere center.</sup>

---

So intersect the two planes, which determine a line through the sphere center,
which pierces the sphere at the arcs intersection point.